# WooCommerce Storefront Header: Hamburger icon on left, search bar on right

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

So I wanted ta have a hamburger image to the left of the search bar in the header.

Removed main menu:

```
add_action('init', 'remove_storefront_header_stuff' );
function remove_storefront_header_stuff(){
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation', 50 );
}
```

Then added it with the same priority as product search:

```
add_action('init', 'add_storefront_header_stuff' );
function add_storefront_header_stuff(){
   add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation', 40 );
}
```

And then some css:

```css
.homeicon {
    background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/pfn_hamburger35x35.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}

.main-navigation {  
    width: 5%;
    float: left !important;
    margin:0;
}

.main-navigation ul.menu > li > a, .main-navigation ul.nav-menu > li > a {
    color:#EDC965;
    opacity: 0;           /*(This was done just to hide the menu text)*/
    padding:1px;
}

.woocommerce-active .site-header .site-search {
    float: right !important;
    width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

The result of this is the hamburger left and search right. As supposed. But the hamburger is below the search and not aligned on the same height. Funny thing is when looking at the mobile now it look pretty perfect with the mobile menu perfectly aligned. But on desktop not so......

What can I do?